# Can 'watcher' be synonymous with 'viewer'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, synonyms

As I understand it, watcher means something different than viewer. A film-watcher is someone who follows cinematography in general and it cannot be used to refer to *anyone who consumes a movie at a given moment* like in the sentence

> The movie invites its ***viewers*** into a mysterious environment.

instead of *viewers*. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but no you're not correct. `watcher` and `viewer` are very close synonyms. If I tried to define the different nuances, I suspect that as many people would agree with me as would disagree.

To be honest, I can't even decide for myself whether `watcher` or `viewer` has the more serious connotation.

Comment: Thanks! So a sentence like *The first thing the watchers of the movie see is a dark scene.* - would be fine?

Comment: You've got one `the` too many, but very close - I would go with: `The first thing watchers of the movie see is a dark scene.`